# How often should you reindex an elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have an OpenSearch domain with 40 data nodes. There is currently one index in the whole cluster. We are a delete-heavy cluster where we are constantly deleting HTML documents and adding new ones. We currently have about 200,000,000 searchable documents and 160,000,000 deleted documents. Would reindexing be a good idea? Also, are there tools you can use to estimate the time it would take to reindex a domain?

Comment: The background merging process should normally get rid of most of the deleted docs regularly. What do you get when running `GET _cat/indices/your-index?v` ?

Comment: ```health index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   XXX XXX 600   1  209748099    212310539    128.4tb         64.2tb```

Comment: You have probably reached the 5 GB limit per segment. What are the first lines when running `GET _cat/segments?v&s=size:desc` ?

Comment: index                       shard prirep ip            segment generation docs.count docs.deleted     size size.memory committed searchable version compound
prod-merchant-analysis-2    190   p      x.x.x.x _1es3u     2369226      33131         6375   14.1gb     1746557 true      true       7.2.1   false

Answer (score 0):

Reindex is not the only option. If you can pause the documents ingestion for a few hours (or maybe days), you can run:

- [split](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-split-index.html) on the index. If you split by a factor 6, you will have no more segments > 5GB and Elasticsearch will merge segments and at the same time free disk space of deleted documents. But this option requires a lot of free disk space. Please read carefully the documentation.
- [forcemerge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/_blocks_during_a_force_merge.html) on the index. I think you will have to specify a value for `max_num_segments` and / or `only_expunge_deletes`. **Warning**: Force merge operation cannot be cancelled and can takes hours on such big shards.

Ideally for the future, you should try to avoid having only one big index because they are harder to operate. Usually, it's possible to distribute documents in multiple indexes by a switch (on first letters of HTML domain name for example).